# Nested form with async upload using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a nested form with many potential files to upload. To make it smoother I want to upload files asynchronously. I'm using carrierwave, so there is a way to upload these files and make a reference to them when I finally send the whome form ?